# Horizontal sort method does not work with as table formated worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel table which is formatted as table (Ctrl+T) and this table I want to sort horizontal each line.

I found a snippet how to sort horizontal https://blog.stefan-macke.com/2006/01/23/zeilen_in_excel_horizontal_sortieren/ and adapted this to my usecase.

```vb
Option Explicit
' sorts cells in all rows of current worksheet ascending from left to right
Sub horizontalSort()
    Dim i, lastRow As Integer
    Const firstColumn As Integer = 15
    Const lastColumn As Integer = 34
    ' find last row
    lastRow = Cells(1, 5).End(xlDown).Row
    ' sort cells in each row ascending from left to right
    For i = 2 To lastRow
       Range(Cells(i, firstColumn), Cells(i, lastColumn)).Select
       Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("O" & i), _
            Order1:=xlDescending, _
            Orientation:=xlSortRows
    Next i
End Sub

' sorts cells in all rows of current worksheet ascending from left to right
Sub horizontalSortOrig()
    Dim i, lastRow As Integer
    Const firstColumn As Integer = 1
    Const lastColumn As Integer = 5
    ' find last row
    lastRow = Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row
    ' sort cells in each row ascending from left to right
    For i = 1 To lastRow
       Range(Cells(i, firstColumn), Cells(i, lastColumn)).Select
       Selection.Sort Key1:=Range("A" & i), _
            Order1:=xlAscending, _
            Orientation:=xlSortRows
    Next i
End Sub
```

If I have an unformated table, the sorting works perfectly. If I "format the table as table" (Ctrl+T) (Insert -> Table) the same makro stops to work.
Does someone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thx @teylyn for the guidens.

Here is the current solution for the problem.

```
' sorts cells in all rows of current worksheet ascending from left to right
Sub horizontalSortOrig()
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim x As Long
    Dim startIndex As Long
    startIndex = 13

    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabelle1")

    For x = 1 To tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows.Count
        Dim myArray As Variant
        myArray = tbl.ListRows(x).Range


        Dim sortArray As Variant
        Dim sortArrayDim As Long
        sortArrayDim = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count - startIndex
        ReDim sortArray(sortArrayDim)
        Dim y, yy As Long
        y = 0
        yy = 0
        For y = startIndex To tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
            sortArray(yy) = myArray(1, y)
            yy = yy + 1
        Next

        Dim nb As Long
        Dim temp_array As Variant
        Dim i, pos, l, ii As Long

        nb = UBound(sortArray)
        temp_array = sortArray
        Erase sortArray
        ReDim sortArray(sortArrayDim)
        For i = 0 To nb
            pos = 0
            For l = 0 To nb
                If temp_array(i) > temp_array(l) And i <> l Then
                    pos = pos + 1
                End If
            Next
            For ii = 1 To 1
                If sortArray(nb - pos) = "" Then
                    sortArray(nb - pos) = temp_array(i)
                Else
                    pos = pos + 1
                    ii = ii - 1
                End If
            Next
        Next

        y = 0
        yy = 0
        For y = startIndex To tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns.Count
            myArray(1, y) = sortArray(yy)
            yy = yy + 1
        Next

        tbl.ListRows(x).Range = myArray
    Next x
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The blog post you're referring to was written before Tables were added to Excel (with Excel 2007). "Formatting" to a table actually turns the cells into a Table Object. That Table Object requires different code than the grid. see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.tableobject or https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/6/20/the-vba-guide-to-listobject-excel-tables for code examples.

Comment: Hi teylyn, thank you, the links helped a lot. But I didn't get it yet how to do the sort. I'll changed the loop and the get methods. But the sorting is still a question `Sub SortHorizontal()
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim x As Long
Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Tabelle1")
For x = 1 To tbl.ListRows.Count
Dim row As Range
Set row = tbl.ListRows(x).Range
Dim cellsToSort As Range
Set cellsToSort = row.Range(cells(x, "C"), cells(x, "F"))
cellsToSort.Sort Key1:=Range("C" & x), _
   Order1:=xlAscending, _
   Orientation:=xlSortRows
Next x
End Sub`

Comment: I'm not even sure if it's possible to sort table columns by name. You could convert the table into a range, then do the sorting with the table elements resolved to normal cells, then turn the result into a table again.

Comment: Wow that's a real brain.... So the choice is to don't use "table formatting" or do the failure shouting double conversion. I should have start writing a new application instead of using excel :(

Comment: I didn't say it was not possible. I just don't know if it is. Sorting a table by the column names is a rather unusual request, so you may understand that it's not a one-click-solution. If you're happy to use VBA to do the sort, what is the problem with converting the table to a range, sort, then re-apply the table? How does that hurt you? It's only a few lines of code.

Comment: with myArray = tbl.DataBodyRange.Rows(x) I get a complete row, but i coudn't figure out how to only get a part of the row